# How does difficulty affect XP rewards in Co-op Vs. AI matches?

Tags: league-of-legends

Previously, in League of Legends, Co-op Vs. AI games would give different XP rewards based on the player's summoner level and the difficulty level of the bots. The old rates can still be see on the League of Legends Wiki [here](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Co-op_vs._AI).

However, the table shown on that page is out of date, as it does not include the "intro" difficulty level or summoner levels beyond 30. The [Riot Support page](https://support-leagueoflegends.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752824-Reward-BE-XP-System-Breakdown) provides updated numbers for how summoner level affects XP rewards (assuming that "Level 30" means "Level 30+"), but makes no mention of how difficulty might affect those rewards.

Does difficulty still affect XP rewards from Co-op Vs. AI games in any way, or are rewards now consistent across all difficulty levels?